# Grouping multidimensional PHP array and calculating sum of a particular key for each arrays element

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I had an array which had data about all projects.

I needed to group the array by 'year_actual' element.

I have successfully done this grouping using a php function “array_group_by” which is available here: https://gist.github.com/mcaskill/baaee44487653e1afc0d

Here is my grouped array which I assigned to a variable: $projects_grouped_by_year

```
Array
(
    [2016] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [project_name] => P1                    
                    [project_capacity] => 100                    
                    [year_actual] => 2016                    
                    [companies] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [project_id] => 1                                    
                                    [company_type] => C1                           
                                    [capacity_share] => 12                                    
                                    [project_year] => 2016
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [project_id] => 1                                    
                                    [company_type] => C2                                    
                                    [capacity_share] => 14                                    
                                    [project_year] => 2016
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [project_name] => P2                    
                    [project_capacity] => 200                    
                    [year_actual] => 2016                    
                    [companies] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [project_id] => 2                                    
                                    [company_type] => C2                                    
                                    [capacity_share] => 15                                    
                                    [project_year] => 2016
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4
                                    [project_id] => 2                                    
                                    [company_type] => C1                                    
                                    [capacity_share] => 16                                    
                                    [project_year] => 2016
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2014] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [project_name] => P3                    
                    [project_capacity] => 300                    
                    [year_actual] => 2014                    
                    [companies] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 5
                                    [project_id] => 3                                    
                                    [company_type] => C1                                    
                                    [capacity_share] => 20                                    
                                    [project_year] => 2014
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 6
                                    [project_id] => 3                                    
                                    [company_type] => C2                                  
                                    [capacity_share] => 22                                    
                                    [project_year] => 2014
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [project_name] => P4                    
                    [project_capacity] => 400                    
                    [year_actual] => 2014                    
                    [companies] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 7
                                    [project_id] => 4                                    
                                    [company_type] => C2                                    
                                    [capacity_share] => 11                                    
                                    [project_year] => 2014
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 8
                                    [project_id] => 4
                                    [company_type] => C1
                                    [capacity_share] => 10
                                    [project_year] => 2014
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am manipulating above array to create a new following resultant array:
I will create a new array and insert the calculated values in this new array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array(
        //year_actual of project
        'year' => 2016,
         //[100+200] : sum of 'project_capacity' where year_actual = 2016 
        'project_capacity_sum' => 300,
         //[12+16] : sum of 'capacity_share' where company_type = C1 and project_year = 2016
        'C1_capacity_sum' => 28,
         //[14+15] : sum of 'capacity_share' where company_type = C2 and project_year = 2016
        'C2_capacity_sum' => 29
        )
    [1] => Array(
         //year_actual of project
        'year' => 2014,
         //[300+400] : sum of 'project_capacity' where year_actual = 2014
        'project_capacity_sum' => 700,
         //[20+10] : sum of 'capacity_share' where company_type = C1 and project_year = 2014
        'C1_capacity_sum' => 30,
         //[22+11] : sum of 'capacity_share' where company_type = C2 and project_year = 2014
        'C2_capacity_sum' => 33
        )
);
```

I have succeeded in calculating the field “project_capacity_sum” using the below code:

`$projectCapacitySum = array_map(function($data) {
            return array_sum(array_column($data, 'project_capacity'));
        }, $projects_grouped_by_year);`

But I am struggling to calculate other fields for the last two days.

The only useful columns to me are following:

[project_capacity]
and
[year_actual]

Inside "companies" sub array

[company_type]
and
[capacity_share]

Basically I am trying group the array by "year_actual" (which i have already done)
Then find the total "project_capacity" in each year and also total "capacity_share" for each "company_type" in each year. I hope this makes sense.

There is no problem if we use column [project_year] inside the [companies] sub array to achieve the desired output.

I know that I have to do another group by inside the companies sub array..and I am still trying to do so.

I am not concerned about code efficiency or optimization at this point. I am just looking for a working logic.

I am asking for help. Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: how are you using the other columns exactly? Give us a code example of what is in fact not working, it is hard to figure this out ourselves.

Comment: The only useful columns to me are following:
For each project inside each year:
[project_capacity] and [year_actual]

Inside "companies" sub array: 
[company_type] and [capacity_share]

Basically I am trying group the array by "year_actual" (which i have already done)
Then find the total "project_capacity" in each year and also total "capacity_share" for each "company_type" in each year. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: There is no problem if we use column [project_year] inside the [companies] sub array to achieve the desired output.

Comment: One more question comes to mind right now though, how are you addressing these company types and shared capacity? Remember that you are in a multidimensional array and will have to do a second "Map" in order to process this. `array.map(function(data){ ... $returnvalue = array.map($secondArrayData) {...}, $data.companies ...}, $projects_by_year);`.

Comment: I know that I have to do another group by inside the companies sub array..and I am still trying to do so.

Comment: At this point I am just looking for just a working solution. I am not bothering about code efficiency and optimization at this point.

Comment: Also the resultant array will be a new one..in which I will inserting the calculated values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the needed result extend your initial solution (`array_map` + `array_sum` + `array_column`) with the following approach:

```
$sumData = array_map(function ($v) {
    $arr = ['year' => current(array_column($v, 'year_actual'))];
    $arr['project_capacity_sum'] = array_sum(array_column($v, "project_capacity"));
    $arr['C2_capacity_sum'] = $arr['C1_capacity_sum'] = 0;

    foreach ($v as $item) {  // iterating through the nested items
        $c_capacities = array_column($item['companies'], 'capacity_share', 'company_type');
        $arr['C1_capacity_sum'] += $c_capacities['C1'];
        $arr['C2_capacity_sum'] += $c_capacities['C2'];
    }

    return $arr;
}, $projects_grouped_by_year);

print_r($sumData);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [2016] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2016
            [project_capacity_sum] => 300
            [C1_capacity_sum] => 28
            [C2_capacity_sum] => 29
        )

    [2014] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2014
            [project_capacity_sum] => 700
            [C1_capacity_sum] => 30
            [C2_capacity_sum] => 33
        )
)
```

Comment: Hi, @RomanPerekhrest. I played with your code and tried to extend it to next level. I succeeded to some extent, but then i found two issues and I am working on that. I posting a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161469/extended-code-grouping-multidimensional-php-array-and-calculating-sum-of-a-part). It would be great if you have a look at it as per your convenience.

Thanks.